# Send array from angularjs to controller

Tags: javascript, c#, angularjs

I have a function with AngularJs what contains some arrays to send the information to controller arrives NULL. Here is the code, help please. Uses Angularjs and C# .Net Core

Function AngularJS

```
$Scope.productos=[];
$scope.OnClickSaveVenta = function () {
        var datajson = {
            productos: JSON.stringify($scope.productos)
        };
        var req = {
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'Ventas/MetodoPrueba',
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            data: JSON.stringify(datajson)
        }
        $http(req).then(
            function (successResponse) {
                if (successResponse.data.isSuccess) {
                    swal.fire("Identificador " + successResponse.data.result, "Registro exitoso!", "info");
                }
                else {
                    swal.fire("Advertencia", successResponse.data.message, "warning");
                    return false;
                }
            }
        )
    }
```

This is my controller

```
[HttpPost]
        [Route("MetodoPrueba")]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Insertar([FromBody] VentaPId productos)
        {
            foreach(var lista in productos.productos)
            {
               
            }
            return Json(new { mensaje = "Datos recibidos" });
          
        }
```

This is my model

```
public class VentaPId
    {
        public List<List<string>> productos { get; set; }
    }
```

Help please,i hope i find a solution